# Performance of iterator list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I'm new to functional programming with Haskell and was wondering if there was any difference with performance between iterate and list comprehension. Right now I'm using `last (takeWhile (< n) (iterate (2*) 1))` to get the highest power of two that can fit in a given number `n`. I would like to optimise this as much as possible. Is there a better way? Without the `last` it would return a list of powers of two lower than `n`. With the `last` it just returns the largest one.

Example: If I input 117 for `n` the output will be `64` and the list would be `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]`.

Comment: Just to note: list comprehension isn't magical. Something like `[f x | x <- xs, p x]` ends up being understood in terms of `map`, `concatMap`, and `filter` (in this case, it's basically `map f (filter p xs)`). Furthermore, `[a .. b]` is just a nice way of saying `enumFromTo a b` (where `enumFromTo` is part of the `Enum` type class).

Comment: @Rhymoid Thanks that's a really nice an concise explanation.

Comment: @Rhymoid, in fact, list comprehensions are translated to `foldr` and `build` forms when optimization is enabled, and to pre-optimized recursive forms otherwise. `map`, `concatMap`, and `filter` are never produced.

Comment: @dfeuer is there an optimalized compilation? How do you enable it?

Comment: If you're using GHC, you'd usually [use `-O2`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#o-convenient-packages-of-optimisation-flags); so rather than running `ghc Main.hs`, you'd run `ghc -O2 Main.hs`. Please note that GHC might not use the [`concatMap`-based approach](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) anyway, regardless of optimisation flags, because it doesn't have to literally do so; it just has to generate code that gives the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it optimisation you're after, you're going about it the wrong way. It is generally always better to optimise the algorithm. (Warning, untested)

The basic algorithm for this is 2^(floor(log2(n)))

Why not:

```
myFunc :: Int -> [Int]
myFunc n = map (2^) list
    where list = [1..x]
          x = floor $ logBase 2 (fromIntegral n)
```

or if you just want the highest power of 2 to a number

```
myFunc2 :: Int -> Int
myFunc2 n = 2 ^ (floor $ logBase 2 (fromIntegral n))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'm not sure if you tested your code or if you typed it from the top of your head but I can't compile it so I'm not fully sure what it does.

Comment: It's untested in afraid. The fromIntegral function converts the Int to a Num a type. logBase 2.0 finds the log2 of the number, and toInteger casts it back to an int, which will round down.2 to the power of the log2 will give the result. All functions can be checked on Hoogle for type.

Comment: I can't compile at the moment to check. Its likely something trivial.

Comment: I have modified your answer a bit `map (2^) [1..(floor $ logBase 2.0 (fromIntegral n))]` but it seems to use more memory than my previous solution. It's also slower so now I'm unsure if I can optimise my first solution.

Comment: `take (x+1) $ iterate (2*) 1` should be faster if you actually access most the elements in the list, as it doesn't have to calculate the powers repetitively. However your implementation of `myFunc` should be faster if most of the elements in the list are not being forced.

Comment: @jpath I'm not really sure what you mean. Is you snippet meant for my version or the one from OllieB?

Comment: @Adrian Z. I mean @OllieB's solution. He uses map (2^) [1..x]. So his solution calculates [2^1, 2^2, 2^3,..,2^x]. But if all of those thunks are actually forced, that is the values are actually looked at and calculated, then it should be more performant to use `iterate`, because that way you only have to multiply by 2 for every value, which should be more efficient than calculating the power (2^). Unless (2^) is optimised to bitwise operations.

Comment: My point was that if you just want to get the largest power of 2, why bother with calculating lists at all? That is what myFunc2 does in the example. If you want to really discuss performance, your test methodology and compiler flags will be helpful.

Comment: Depending on the representation of the underlying type, 2^n is a simple bitshift, which can often be faster than multiplication. Really, to discuss this, the target architecture, compiler flags, and test setup are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

A *much* simpler answer is to use recursion directly.

```
foo 1 = 1
foo x = 2 * foo (div x 2)
```

Comment: Simpler maybe, but not obviously fast for large x.

Comment: It's basically the same algorithm as the `iterate`- and `map`-based approaches; I'm just not creating an explicit list of all the smaller powers of 2 at the same time. It returns nearly instantly for 1000-digit numbers. (Granted, I tested with a hard-coded 1000-digit number, so `ghc -O2` appears to have completely unrolled the loop to get the answer...)

Comment: Agreed. In the example I give, myFunc2 does this in constant rather than linear time (assuming logbase 2 is constant time)

Comment: It's only constant time for `Int`, since the input size is bounded. For `Integer`, it's logarithmic in the magnitude of the input, just like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
  largestPowerOfTwoIn n = until ((>n).(*2)) (*2) 1
```

where the [Prelude.until](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#until) idiom yields a constant-space tail-recursive iteration to your end result.